# How to limit Min-Max Time in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, logic

How to limit

I'm trying to limit the time a user can select from this plugin: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've searched around this site and google for similar questions, but users generally ask for the validation to work between one known period and another known period. e.g 9:00 - 21:00 2015/03/09 9:00 - 2015/03/10 21:00. If a user inputs 2015/03/09 23:00 the validation will pass this because the time is within those two min/max periods.

I need it to work as a booking system works, so that each day is limited between those times. e.g if a user selects 2015/03/09 23:00 or 2015/03/10 5:00 then the validation won't pass, it will only pass on any day between 9:00 & 21:00.

```
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
       stepping: 30,
       minDate: moment({hour: 9, minute: 30}),
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
    });
```

This starts the min date for today at 9:30am, but if I was to choose any day after today I would be able to select for example 4am - anything under 9:30am

Answer (score 12):

Use the enabledHours property:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   stepping: 30,
   enabledHours: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
});
```

This way it should allow any hours between 9:00 and 20:30, but won't allow anything from 21:00 on.  More at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#endisabledhours.